# Symfony2 : How to translate a template in a service

Tags: templates, symfony, dependency-injection, translation, twig

I created a service in which I inject translator & templating services.
I use it to send mail from controllers.

Everything works fine, except that the twig template used to generate the email body is not translated.

I think that templating in service doesn't use the request locale of the calling controller, and use the default one, set for all the app.
How can I set the locale to tell the injected templating service to use it?

There is my code:

```
class Mailer
{
private $mailer;
private $templating;
private $siteUrl;
private $fromName;
private $fromAddress;
private $translator;
private $doctrine;


/**
 * @param \Swift_Mailer     $mailer
 * @param EngineInterface   $templating
 * @param RegistryInterface $doctrine
 * @param Translator        $translator
 * @param string            $siteUrl
 * @param string            $fromName
 * @param string            $fromAddress
 */
public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, EngineInterface $templating, Translator $translator, $siteUrl = "", $fromName = "", $fromAddress = "")
{
    $this->mailer      = $mailer;
    $this->templating  = $templating;
    $this->siteUrl     = $siteUrl;
    $this->fromName    = $fromName;
    $this->fromAddress = $fromAddress;
    $this->doctrine    = $doctrine;
    $this->translator  = $translator;
}

public function sendIndentConfirm(Indent $indent)
{
    $customer  = $indent->getCustomer();
    $purchases = $indent->getPurchases();

    $subject = $this->translator->trans("Confirmation of your order");

    $customerBody = $this->templating->render('ZamaECommerceBundle:Mailer:indentCustomerConfirm.html.twig', array(
        "indent"  => $indent,
        "subject" => $subject
    ));

    $this->sendEmail(
        $customerBody,
        $subject,
        array(
            $customer->getUsername() => $customer->getFirstName() . " " . $customer->getLastName()
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `$locale` as an argument when calling the `sendIndentConfirm` method in your controller.

```
public function sendIndentConfirm(Indent $indent, $locale)
{
    $this->translator->setLocale($locale);

    $customer = $indent->getCustomer();
    $purchases = $indent->getPurchases();

    // Rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was in my xliff file...
No problem with my service everything works well.